# Rails Admin and dealing with Calculated Totals,Subtotals and Discount fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

Ok so I have a table orders, order_items, and items. Everything works fine except for 1 thing.

```
    class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
      def change
        create_table :orders do |t|
          t.integer :seller_id
          t.integer :customer_id
          t.string :shipping_method
          t.string :shipping_terms
          t.string :payment_method
          t.date :delivery_date
          t.date :due_date
          t.decimal :total_discount, :precision =>8, :scale => 2
          t.decimal :subtotal, :precision =>8, :scale => 2
          t.decimal :sales_tax, :precision =>8, :scale => 2
          t.decimal :total, :precision =>8, :scale => 2

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
    class CreateOrderItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
      def change
        create_table :order_items do |t|
          t.integer :order_id
          t.integer :item_id
          t.integer :quantity
          t.decimal :discount, :precision =>8, :scale => 2
          t.decimal :line_total, :precision =>8, :scale => 2
          t.boolean :packed
          t.string :packed_by
          t.string :ffr

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
    class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
      def change
        create_table :items do |t|
          t.integer :sku
          t.string :name
          t.decimal :price, :precision =>8, :scale => 2
          t.string :description
          t.decimal :weight, :precision =>8, :scale => 2
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

Basically there needs to be calculations done either as the items are being added to the order or before everything is saved.

On the Orders table the following needs to happen

> Calculate : total_discount(dollar amount), sub_total, :sales_tax, :total

On OrderItems table the following needs to happen

> Calculate : line_total, discount(dollar amount)

There has to be a sane way to do this but I have yet to figure it out. Either I really do not know what I am looking for or I am googling all the wrong things.

Comment: You could use before_save action on the model.

Comment: If the order_items are not saved how would I do that. I have used before_save before but I will be missing all the order items and their data to process. I will look more into before_save.